# How to paramiko-sftp traffic limit

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I use paramiko-sftp.
The Linux SFTP command has a -l option.
However, there is no way to control bandwidth in paramiko-sftp.
Can't the same thing be achieved with the -l option?

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko does not have a built-in speed throttle.

But you can trottle the speed by smartly implementing the `callback` of [`SFTPClient.put`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) or [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get). A naive implementation would be to simple `time.sleep` a bit, when the speed it too high.

Similar question for ftplib:
[Throttling FTP download with Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42912898/850848)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
We will refer to the information you received.